# How to push into gitlab again when the docker-volume or the server data is recreated?

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, git-push

I have gitlab installed in a docker container. 
I have loaded my server backup of 2 days ago due to few problem on the server. So my gitlab is not up to date and lose the code of 2 days.

My problem is that on client side, developpers already pushed some code and the server lose them.

How to push again properly ?

Comment: Please remove irrelevant tag `gitlab-ci-runner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your developers run a `git pull` they should be able to `git push` their (since your backup only local) commits to the `remote` again.